# Cordova plugin to check support of 'Face Id' and 'Touch Id'?

Tags: cordova-plugins, fingerprint, face-id

Is there a cordova plugin to check support of 'Face Id' and 'Touch Id'?
And is there a way to use these authentication methods without showing the native popup (to add a custom animation for instance)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin support Touch ID and Face ID : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fingerprint-aio

Native authentication popup cannot be skipped on hybrid or native app, it not depends on cordova.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this plugin
https://github.com/Cheney925/ionic-for-cordova-plugin-ios-faceid

It works but needs some fixes. I have two pull requests open.
https://github.com/Cheney925/cordova-plugin-ios-faceid/pull/1
https://github.com/Cheney925/cordova-plugin-ios-faceid/pull/3

When they get merged, it will meet all of my needs.